# Header of the Page scrolls up with the page when I click on a textfield lies at the bottom of that page

Tags: jquery, ios, html, css

I want Header to be remain fixed when there is a focus on the bottom components of that page.
Only page should scroll, header should show on screen.

This is the html I am trying to make work

```
<div id="one" style="position: absolute !important" data-role="header" data-id="poc-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <h1 class="translate" id="txt1">DEMO</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I tried with data-position:fixed but its not working.

Comment: There should be no data at the beginning of that. The property you are looking for is `position: fixed;`

Comment: so, Do I need to apply it like style=position:fixed as div's first property?

Comment: If you put your html in your question, it might be easier to understand where the problem is.

Comment: <div id="one"  style="position: absolute !important" data-role="header" data-id="poc-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
 <h1 class="translate" id="txt1">DEMO</h1>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you are looking for

```
<div id="one" style="position: fixed; top: 0px" data-role="header" data-id="poc-header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <h1 class="translate" id="txt1">DEMO</h1>
</div>
```

[I have made a fiddle too, here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/d5eprxxd/)

Answer (score 0):

this will fix the header to the top:

```
<div id="one" style="position: fixed !important" data-role="header" id="poc_header"  data-tap-toggle="false">
  <h1 class="translate" id="txt1">DEMO</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it must work, you can check the code in action if you visit my website from my profile with an iPhone

Comment: No, it is not working for me in iOS. I have a textfield at the bottom of the page, when I click inside that textfield, virtual keypad pops up and page scrolls up and header is not visible. When I scroll page downwards, then i am able to see header.

Comment: I'm afraid that problem is on iOS side and has nothing to do with your code, the solution is to hand-make (kind of a workaround) the inputs in your page if you don't want this to happen

Comment: also worth mentioning that this situation only happens if you're not using safari (the built in iOS browser)